# VUEJS + Firestore how to output Data?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I created a post and stored it in `Cloud Firestore` and now I would like to output the data in my `vueJs` file called `Dashboard.vue`.

But I do not know how it works. I tried some ideas by myself without a good end result.

So how can I output this data?

Files:

```
Firebase => Cloud Firestore
```

created post data in firebase:
[image: created post data in firebase]

and

create post method in `vueJs` `post.vue`

```
    createPost () {
       fb.postsCollection.add({
        postDetails: {
        createdOn: this.postDetails.createdOn,
        content: this.postDetails.content,
        userId: this.currentUser.uid,
        image: this.postDetails.image,
        comments: this.postDetails.comments,
        likes: this.postDetails.likes
      }
      }).then(ref => {
          this.post.content = ''
          this.$router.push('/dashboard')
      }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do as follows:

Create a `posts` array in your data:

```
...
data() {
    return {
        posts: []
    }
},
....
```

Then create a method that fetches the records and assigns the result to the `posts` array:

```
 methods:{
   getPosts: function() {

    fb.postsCollection.orderBy('createdOn', 'desc').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        let postsArray = []

        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            let post = doc.data()
            post.id = doc.id
            postsArray.push(post)
        })

        this.posts = postsArray;
    })

   }
 },
 .....
```

Call the method in the `beforeMount()` lifecycle hook:

```
 beforeMount(){
    this.getPosts()
 },
```

Then render the posts out to the DOM. For example:

```
<div v-if="posts.length">
    <div v-for="post in posts">
        <h4>{{ post.createdOn }}</h4>
        <p>{{ post.content}}</p>
        <ul>
            <li>comments {{ post.comments }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div v-else>
    <p>There are currently no posts</p>
</div>
```